# Displaying an Access table in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I was wondering the best way to display the data from an MS Access table. I need to be able to display all the data in one big list on a single form. I know how to connect to the database, show data one item at a time and navigate through the records, but not how to get the whole row to show.
Thanks in Advance,
Rinslep

Comment: Try Google. There is a ton of information out there on this. Search for something like "vb.net displaying database information" or "vb.net databinding" or "vb.net datagridview".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DataReader or a DataTable you can use one of the standard WinForms components like the DataGridView to display the entirety of the record set.  You would drag a DataGridView onto your form and then load it something like this (assuming you already have your bindable object).

```
' dr representing an IDataReader object
DataGridView1.DataSource = dr
```

If you want to use something like a ListView I would search for implementations of binding to one as it's not natively supported (there are many examples on the web of people writing helper methods to facilitate binding objects to the ListView).